# Example of Coherent Risk measure with Compact Representation

Tags: risk-management, coherent-risk-measure

Every coherent risk measure $\rho$ can be represented as
$$
\rho(X)\triangleq \sup_{Q \in \mathcal{Q}} \mathbb{E}\left[
-X
\right],
$$
for a set of probability measures $\mathcal{Q}$ defined on the same measurable space.  Many of which, we know closed-form expression for (ie.: no sup, inf, or limits).

My question is, is there a known coherent risk-measure such that

- $\rho$ is coherent
- $\mathcal{Q}$ is compact in the set of probability measures, all dominated by a single probability measure $\mathbb{P}$.
- (Optional) $\rho$ has a known closed-form?